# python multithreading. How to prevent multiple threads from running on the gpu

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using multithreading to read files and obtain some data and then I am processing those data with a gpu accelerated function. My system has only one gpu, hence I think, I should be allowing only one thread to run on my gpu at any given time.

My program looks as follows

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def my_fun():
    urls = [url_1, url_2,....,url_n]
    pool = ThreadPool(1) # <--- Single thread!
    pool.map(read_and_process, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def read_and_process(url):
    data = read(url) # io bound
    process(data)    # runs on gpu
```

As you can see at the moment I am making a pool with only one thread. If I change that the program crashes (i think because of the reason outlined just above). That obviously makes the multithreading set up meaningless. A simple loop would achieve the same result in the same time.

Is there a way to benefit from multithreading on my io bound operation and at the same time prevent multiple threads from accessing my gpu? A lock maybe?

In more general terms, from a design perspective does something like make sense?

I wouldnt like to remove the process() call from inside read_and_process. The data each url returns is more than 600MB and I have 1000s of these. Storing them in memory with the plan of iterating over them when all are parsed and send them to the gpu function (outside the multithreading call)  will not work as they do not fit my memory.

**Edit**: I have been reading this nice [post](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-mutex-lock/) and I try to adapt it. So far I have changed the code above to something like:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Lock

def my_fun():
    urls = [url_1, url_2,....,url_n]
    lock = Lock()
    items = [(d, lock) for d in urls]

    with ThreadPool(4):
        pool.starmap_async(read_and_process, items)
    

def read_and_process(url, lock):
    data = read(url) # io bound
    with lock:
        process(data)    # runs on gpu
```

which looks to work but still I am not 100% sure. Could someone please review it and help me some feedback? It will be massively appreciated

Comment: As your `process()` function is not scaling onto multiple threads, the `Lock` approach seems to be sufficient. Further considerations can include decomposing `process` func to check if there any parts within that does not directly call GPU and can be moved out as a separate logical unit/function outside of the lock.

Comment: yes, using a simple Lock is the way to go in cases like this.

Comment: also, on a side note, there is _no problem_ in passing your "data"  as a parameter to different functions: Python  does not create a duplicate of any data passed as parameters to functions, it just increases an internal reference count accordingly.